# Why can't I see anything when I turn on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: setup

I have connected an HDMI cable to my TV and Raspberry Pi Zero. Its a fresh Raspberry Pi with no Operating System installed. When I plug the adopter and turn the plug of the adoptor on, nothing shows up on the screen. How can I turn it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch on with an SD card containing an operating system inserted in the Pi's SD card slot.  Otherwise nothing will happen.

Comment: I thought it had some basic system in its ROM. It doesn't have a ROM?

Comment: @FahadUddin It has a ROM which loads the boot program from SD card (or other simple devices) and then executes the loaded boot program.  The Pi does not have a BIOS like system you would have on a PC.